# MongoDB get results where date is equal to max date

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume I have the following document:

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17dac51e-125e-499e-9064-f20bd3b1a9d8",
    "caller": {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Testing",
      "phoneNumber": "1231231234"
    },
    "routeHistory": [
      {
        "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
        "routeDate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
        "status": "routed"
      },
      {
        "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
        "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
        "status": "ended"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get results where routeHistory.routeDate is equal to the $max routeDate value in routeHistory. I would expect my results to look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17dac51e-125e-499e-9064-f20bd3b1a9d8",
    "caller": {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Testing",
      "phoneNumber": "1231231234"
    },
    "routeHistory": [
      {
        "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
        "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
        "status": "ended"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a clean way to do this in a single aggregate, so that additional $match criteria can be applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to define temporary variable being `$max` date and the use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) along with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get first matching element:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            routeHistory: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        maxDate: { $max: "$routeHistory.routeDate" }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                            { $filter: { input: "$routeHistory", cond: { $eq: [ "$$maxDate", "$$this.routeDate" ] } } },
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C9T1yTVwXkW)

EDIT:

version without `$let`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            maxDate: {
                $max: "$routeHistory.routeDate"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            routeHistory: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                        $filter: { input: "$routeHistory", cond: { $eq: [ "$$maxDate", "$$this.routeDate" ] } }
                    },
                    0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: this solution works, however $let is not supported by Amazon DocumentDB. Is there a way around having to use that operator by chance?

Comment: @MichaelKitchell sure, you just need to run another `$addFields` to add that variable to your model: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JS9yQhRG1c2

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question, what would my query look like if instead the routeHistory was nested within another array? See for example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8mtrYKvhA5w

Comment: @MichaelKitchell that;s miore complicated since you have to flatten the array of arrays before you apply `$max`. You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101367/merge-documents-with-its-nested-arrays-and-their-nested-arrays/57101715#57101715 if you can't make it please open another question

Comment: I have opened another question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326430/mongodb-get-max-date-inside-double-nested-array