# Nested $addFields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17dac51e-125e-499e-9064-f20bd3b1a9d8",
    "caller": {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Testing",
      "phoneNumber": "1231231234"
    },
    "inquiries": [
      {
        "inquiryId": "b0d14381-ce75-49aa-a66a-c36ae20b72a8",
        "routeHistory": [
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "routed"
          },
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "routed"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "inquiryId": "9d743be9-7613-46d7-8f9b-a04b4b899b56",
        "routeHistory": [
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "ended"
          },
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "ended"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I'm using the following aggregate:

```
{
  $unwind: '$inquiries',
},
{
  $addFields: {
    'inquiries.routeHistory': {
      $filter: {
        input: '$inquiries.routeHistory',
        cond: {
          $eq: [{ $max: '$inquiries.routeHistory.routeDate' }, '$$this.routeDate'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    callId: { $first: '$callId' },
    caller: { $first: '$caller' },
    inquiries: { $push: '$inquiries' },
  },
}
```

I would like to expand this query to be able to further filter at the inquiry grain, so that I am returning only the inquiry that contains my specified criteria. E.g. if I wanted to find where `inquiry.routeHistory.status = ended`, I would expect the following results:

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17dac51e-125e-499e-9064-f20bd3b1a9d8",
    "caller": {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Testing",
      "phoneNumber": "1231231234"
    },
    "inquiries": [
      {
        "inquiryId": "9d743be9-7613-46d7-8f9b-a04b4b899b56",
        "routeHistory": [
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "ended"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do nested `$addField` or is there another route I could take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `$unwind` you can do that easily by adding `$match` since expression: `"inquiries.routeHistory.status": "ended"` will return `true` if there's **any** document in `routeHistory` having such status:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$inquiries"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "inquiries.routeHistory.status": "ended"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "inquiries.routeHistory": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$inquiries.routeHistory",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ { $max: "$inquiries.routeHistory.routeDate" }, "$$this.routeDate" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            callId: { $first: "$callId" },
            caller: { $first: "$caller" },
            inquiries: { $push: "$inquiries" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WPeW0x6s0UM)

Comment: is there a way to improve the performance when working with a larger dataset? It seems like the $unwind is very resource-heavy. I've opened a new ticket here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60380863/mongodb-unwind-and-performance

Comment: That's true, you should not be using it and the only reason is that `$map` is not supported. You can try to rethink your algorithm and maybe put some kind of filtering `$match` in front of `$unwind` if possible