# MongoDB $unwind and performance

Tags: mongodb

Below is a small example of my data:

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17dac51e-125e-499e-9064-f20bd3b1a9d8",
    "caller": {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Testing",
      "phoneNumber": "1231231234"
    },
    "inquiries": [
      {
        "inquiryId": "b0d14381-ce75-49aa-a66a-c36ae20b72a8",
        "routeHistory": [
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "routed"
          },
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "routed"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "inquiryId": "9d743be9-7613-46d7-8f9b-a04b4b899b56",
        "routeHistory": [
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "ended"
          },
          {
            "assignedUserId": "cfa0ffe9-c77d-4eec-87d7-4430f7772e81",
            "routeDate": "2020-01-03T06:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "ended"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am running the following aggregate against many more documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$inquiries"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "inquiries.routeHistory.status": "ended"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "inquiries.routeHistory": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$inquiries.routeHistory",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ { $max: "$inquiries.routeHistory.routeDate" }, "$$this.routeDate" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            callId: { $first: "$callId" },
            caller: { $first: "$caller" },
            inquiries: { $push: "$inquiries" }
        }
    }
])
```

While this does return the expected results, it does not scale. When I run this against a much larger dataset, I'm getting timeouts. I have indexes on the fields I am querying against. Is there a way to optimize my query for better performance?

**Important note:** I am limited to only using operators supported by [DocumentDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't scale because indexes can be applied if `$match` (and others, take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance)) occurs at the beginning of a pipeline

Make sure you have this [multi-key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-index) index: `{'inquiries.routeHistory.status' : 1}`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "inquiries.routeHistory.status": "ended"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$inquiries"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "inquiries.routeHistory.status": "ended"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "inquiries.routeHistory": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$inquiries.routeHistory",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $max: "$inquiries.routeHistory.routeDate"
              },
              "$$this.routeDate"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      callId: {
        $first: "$callId"
      },
      caller: {
        $first: "$caller"
      },
      inquiries: {
        $push: "$inquiries"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Note:** It's sad, DocumentDB doesn't support `$map`, in that case, we could solve it with [2 $addFields](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pz1JX6vbaJD)